# SAS macro convert integer to hexadecimal string

Tags: sas

Suppose I have the following macro variable assignment:

```
%let x=42165;
```

How can I get the corresponding hex string representation?  That is, how can I transform `&x` and store it into `&y` such that

```
%put y=&y;
```

writes

```
y=A4B5
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
%let y=%sysfunc(putn(&x.,hex4.));
```

[I think there's no `%put()` macro function to avoid confustion with the `%put` macro statement.]

Comment: How do you know to use `4` for the format `hex<#>.`?

Comment: It specifies the length of the output string.  If your numbers range higher than #FFFF, you'll want to pick something bigger.

Comment: There's no `%put()` because this isn't really a normal usage of the macro language.  `put()` and `put` (log/file writing) both exist in the data step language.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the HEX string representation, you may want to do it inside a Datastep Program.

Here is how:

```
%let x=42165;
%put &x;

%let y=;

data _null_;
    call symput('y',put(&x,hex4.));
run;

%put &y;
```

This works. If you need to store the value into a Dataset, just modify the program.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's answer is fine, but if you're generating `&x` as the output of a data step function via `%sysfunc`, you can save a few characters by applying the format using %sysfunc itself, e.g.

```
%let y = %sysfunc(sum(42000, 165), hex4.);
```